# Invalid hook call while using no hooks (material-ui v5)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following simple application:

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          a
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          b
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          c
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          d
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code compiles without errors or warnings. However, at runtime, it throws this:

```
react.development.js:1476 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476)
    at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1484)
    at useTheme (useTheme.js:4)
    at useStyles (makeStyles.js:222)
    at WithStyles (withStyles.js:55)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:17044)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19098)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1476
useContext @ react.development.js:1484
useTheme @ useTheme.js:4
useStyles @ makeStyles.js:222
WithStyles @ withStyles.js:55
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14985
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:17044
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19098
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23964
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
./src/index.js @ index.js:7
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in the latest material-ui? I've been Googling for hours and found no solution to this problem.

Comment: Do you have two versions of React on the page?

Comment: @JaredSmith no, it is a clean, new project created using create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using material-ui (V5), you'll first need to update the package names and then the import statement to this:

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
```

For more info, check out the changelogs - [Migration from v4 to v5](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/)

Comment: Just tried it with this change. Did not solve the problem, although it is true this is the new import name.

Comment: @Frantisek can you provide a CodePen / CodeSandBox link, replicating the same scenario?

Comment: I'm trying, but the v5 seems kinda broken on CodeSandBox ...

Comment: For this to work, you'll have to install `@mui/material`, `@emotion/styled` & `@emotion/react` packages. Take a look at this CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-leftpad-xv15g

Comment: now I don't get it ... I created an identical project as the one you posted, copy pasted everything. It compiles without any error/warning. Console still shows that error though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the package.json file? or Can you provide the GitHub link for the project?

Comment: I copy-pasted that too...

Comment: Okay, try deleting the node_modules and package-lock.json/yarn.lock file and run `npm install` again

Comment: OK, that fixed it! Do you have any idea how that was possible and how can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: It seems like your app was running some older version of material-ui and even after updating the package.json file, it will still throw an error and that's because your package-lock.json file still has the older version. So to update it, we've deleted the older version lock file and freshly installed all the deps.